# Extracting tweets with tweepy

Tags: python, machine-learning, twitter, tweepy

I have tried using tweepy to extract tweets for a specific keyword.But the count of extracted tweets using tweepy is less compared those tweets for the specific keyword as seen on twitter search.
Also I want to know how to effectively extract ALL the tweets for a specific keyword of interest using any twitter data extracting library (tweepy/twython).
I also face a problem of irrelevant tweets with same keyword coming up.Is there a way to fine tune search and perform accurate extraction so that I get all the tweets extracted for the specific keyword.
Im adding the code snippet as many asked for it.But I don't have a problem with the code as its running.

```
tweets = api.search('Mexican Food', count=500,tweet_mode = 'extended')
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets], columns 
['Tweets'])
data.head(10)
print(tweets[0].created_at)
```

My question is that how to get ALL the tweets with a particular keyword.For example when I run the above code ,for each time I am getting different count of tweets.Also I cross checked with doing manual search on twitter and it seems that there are much more tweets than extracted through tweepy for the particular keyword.
Also I want to know if there is any way to fine tune the keyword search through python so that all the relevant tweets for my keyword of interest is fetched.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a tripped down version of your code ?

Comment: Actually this is a general doubt where i am looking for some recommendation.I don't have any problem with code or extraction of tweets .I only want to say that the ones extracted are smaller in count to the ones seen on twitter app via search .And also looking for someway to get all the tweets with specific keywords basically fine tuning

Answer (score 1):

The thing is when you use tweepy It has some limitation. It won't be able to fetch older tweets. 
So I will suggest you to use 
https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python
in place of tweepy to fetch the older tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you refuse to help me with your question, I'll do the bare minimum with my answer:

You are probably not doing pagination correctly

ps: Check out the [stack overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There is an important point about **Helping others reproduce the problem**